# Calculate sum of column values based on dynamic starting date in R

Tags: r, calculation

good afternoon!

Currently I’m working on calculating one financial metric and my goal is to calculate the total sum of debt repayments starting from the dynamically selected date. In the code attached I have created a table where columns “debt_repayment_x.x.x_x.x.x” stand for the sums repaid by the borrowers. I want to calculate the sum of these columns automatically given the condition that the starting date (default date) is changing constantly. For example, if it is “2020-01-06” then we have to sum all the columns starting from “Debt_Repayment_2020.02.01_2020.02.28” and so on.

Which code should I create in order to automate this calculation?

```
Borrower_ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Default_Date <- c(“2020-01-06”, “2020-02-17”, “2020-03-20”, “2020-04-21”, “2020-05-21”)
Debt_Repayment_2020.01.01_2020.01.31 <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
Debt_Repayment_2020.02.01_2020.02.28 <- c(20,30,40,50,60)
Debt_Repayment_2020.03.01_2020.03.31 <- c(30,40,50,60,70)
Debt_Repayment_2020.04.01_2020.04.30 <- c(40,50,60,70,80)
Debt_Repayment_2020.05.01_2020.05.31 <- c(50,60,70,80,90)

table_test <- data.frame(Borrower_ID, Default_Date, Debt_Repayment_2020.01.01_2020.01.31, Debt_Repayment_2020.02.01_2020.02.28, Debt_Repayment_2020.03.01_2020.03.31, Debt_Repayment_2020.04.01_2020.04.30, Debt_Repayment_2020.05.01_2020.05.31)
```

Comment: I'd advise to use `tidy data` and separate the debt repayment values from the dates the debt was repaid. If your data was in long format instead of wide, you could simply do an easy filtering.